# Intelligently redirect based on where :back symbol points to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have an application that allows an admin user to switch into another user's context. If the admin is in `/images` and switches to another user's context, the admin will see the `Images` belonging to that user. I have a `ContextController` that switches the context, and then, upon success, redirects the user to `:back`.

This is great, and works well. The problem is that, if the admin is viewing `/images/1`, and switches into another user's context, an error will be thrown (because `Image` with `id=1` does not belong to that user).

One way I could handle this is to catch the error, and redirect the user to `root_path`. I would like a more intelligent way to handle this, however, if anybody has any ideas. Is there a nice programmatic way to check where `:back` points to, and extract the `:action` from that path?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:back` is just using the http referer header which you can look at in `request.referer` It will be a full URL, so it won't be as easy as checking the action, you'll need to match against the full string url. Make sure to handle the case when `request.referer` is nil or empty as well.